# Is it possible to convert a basic disk to dynamic disk without losing data in Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, partition, diskpart

I am not able to extend partition in windows server 2008. We have two different partitions which we want to join and make one partition. I came to know that basic disks have limitation of 2 TB each partition and we can create a maximum of 4 partition due to limitations.

Comment: By the way, my answer is correct with regards to converting to Dynamic Disks, but you can't simply merge partitions like that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your data will be fine, though you should always ensure your backups are maintained and up to date before doing such critical operations.

Here is a Technet article which will guide you through the process and some key considerations:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731274.aspx

Answer (score -1):

**I think minitool Partition Wizard do this
http://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/partition-wizard-home.html**